# How to serve Angular images in Django app?

Tags: django, angular

I have an Angular app and placed images in assets/img.  I am loading them as such:

```
src="/assets/img/img_name.png"
```

Now I also serve my Angular app from a Django app.  After running ng build and placing all static files in my_app/static/. I can't seem to serve the images from the Django app however.

If I add /static/ in front of assets and build the it will work. However this is cumbersome and means I can't view the Angular during development.

Comment: Are you using Django rest services which get consumed by angular?

Comment: No I am not using rest services yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming django is serving the page whilst you're using Angular as front-end? In which case, add `--deploy-url /static/` to your `ng-build` command.

Comment: --deploy-url  is deprecated in current angular version. Is there any other option?